# Comet Chat Pro Audio/Video Call API Support

Tags: react-native, cometchat

Is there any option or workaround to implement audio and video calling using comet chat pro API in react native. I have seen in the [doc](https://prodocs.cometchat.com/docs/react-native-quick-start) as it's not supported, but I wanted to know if anyone has found any workaround or solution.

I have already tried implementing the code, the call is getting connected and the users are joining successfully. Also, all the events are working fine. The only issue is sound is not audible or not working.

React Native is so popular and many developers use it and it's sad that Comet chat is not supporting it.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Hi there!

We are adding support for React Native video calling within the next 1-2 weeks. Please reach out at help (at) cometchat.com and we will update you when this feature is available.

Comment: Please make it as early as possible. I have already added an entry in comet chat pro forum. I have already used this api for chat in my project. It was not mentioned that it's not supporting call for react native.